# rssLounge weird issue with greek characters

Tags: php, rss

I have just installed rsslounge 1.7 but I am experiencing a wierd issue.
When rsslounge loads, everything seems **ok**, but when the rss elements are **refreshed** (for instance I click on a category on the left), the rss elements's contents turn into "?". This behaviour is happening on **Greek** characters only.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and fixed it by changing a single line:
http://code.google.com/p/rsslounge/source/browse/trunk/application/controllers/ItemController.php#80

Replace it with the following one:

```
'html' => $this->view->render('item/list.'.Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer')->getViewSuffix()),
```

Basically, you remove the utf_encode/decode calls...

This isn't a perfect full solution (other small problems remain), but you at least get a functional rss reader ;).

Edit: Go to config/config.ini and add the following line:
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"

This should fix everything (your old rss items will not be printed correctly though).

Comment: This may be reading comprehension fail on my part, but scanning through your answer made me think the config.ini edit made the ItemController.php edit unnecessary. Might be worth explicitly stating both are necessary, or grouping them in an ordered list.